# Проблема при обновлении приложения в Google Play

Tags: google-play, обновление

Создал год назад приложение в App Inventor 2. Его скачало довольно большое количество человек. Подготовил обновление, однако Google не загружает его вот по этой причине:

[image: Ошибка при загрузке: APK-пакет должен иметь название...]

Название файла поменял. Не знаю, в чём проблема.

Comment: А вы точно bundle оно же имя пакета не поменяли?

Comment: Да, спасибо)) Я уже понял. Переименовал файл в программе и сохранил. Полет нормальный)

Answer (score 0):

В самом пакете нужно имя изменить[image: введите сюда описание изображения]